# Given finite $X \neq \emptyset$ together with an associative binary operation, if left-cancellation and right-cancellation laws hold, is $X$ a group?

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification

**Problem Statement**

> Given finite $X \neq \emptyset$ together with an associative binary operation, if left-cancellation and right-cancellation laws hold, is $X$ a group?

**Attempt**

We know that for all $x, y, z \in X$, left-cancellation
$$xy = xz \implies y = z$$
holds.  Thus, the function $L_{x}:X \to X$ defined by
$$L_{x}(w)=xw$$
is injective.  Since $X$ is finite, $L_{x}$ must also be surjective.  This means that there exists an element $e$ of $X$ such that $L_{x}(e)=x$, i.e. $x=xe$.

First, we want to show that $e$ is in fact a two-sided identity for $X$.  So let $v$ be an arbitrary element of $X$, and consider $xv=(xe)v=x(ev)$ (by associativity).  Thus, by left-cancellation, $v=ev$ for all $v$, i.e. $e$ is a left identity.  Now consider $vv=v(ev)=(ve)v$ (again, by associativity).  By right-cancellation, we conclude that $v=ve$, i.e. $e$ is a right identity.

Next, we need to show the existence of inverses.  From before, for every $w \in X$, the function $x \mapsto wx$ is surjective, so there is an element, say $w_R$, such that $w{w_R} = e$.  Similarly, there is an element $w_L$ such that ${w_L}w = e$.  Since $$w_L = {w_L}e = {w_L}(w{w_R}) = ({w_L}w){w_R} = e{w_R} = w_R,$$ we conclude that $w_L = w_R$ is a two-sided inverse for $w$.

**Caveat**

But wait!  I have not yet established closure of the binary operation!

Additionally, I also need to show that the result in this problem may be false if $X$ is infinite.

Any hints you can provide will be gladly appreciated!

**Question**

> Is my attempt above acceptable for the given problem at hand?  Or would there be a more direct approach?

Comment: Also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/512011/29335) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/510157/29335), all visible in the related questions column, and likely visible to you as you wrote the question.